# Re-writing simple Task snippet as a separate re-usable function

Tags: c#, task

What I want to avoid is duplication the code each time I use this function:

```
waitUntilFilledTask = Task.Run(() => {  
                        while ((myGenericCombobox.Items.Count == 0)) {
                            Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
                        }     
                     } );
```

All the options I have tried to build it as a reusable function have failed to achieve the same result as the code shown below. To explain what the code does: I have several comboboxes. When one item is selected in the first combobox, the next combobox is automatically populated.

The global goal of my piece of code is: I have a `favorite`, which contains properties that must be selected in each combobox... but each combobox is filled with the content only when the previous item in the previous combobox has been properly selected.

(I have translated the code from vb.net, so please excuse me if there are some typos...)

```
Task waitUntilFilledTask = default(Task);

this.cbxGroups.SelectedItem = favorite.GroupName;

// To be reused? (1)
waitUntilFilledTask = Task.Run(() => {  
                        while ((cbxDatasets.Items.Count == 0)) {
                            Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
                        }     
                     } );
await Task.WhenAll(waitUntilFilledTask );

this.cbxDatasets.SelectedItem = favorite.DatasetName;

// To be reused? (2)
waitUntilFilledTask = Task.Run(() => {  
                        while ((cbxStations.Items.Count == 0)) {
                            Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
                        }     
                     } );
await Task.WhenAll(waitUntilFilledTask );

this.cbxStations.SelectedItem = favorite.StationName;

// To be reused? (3)
waitUntilFilledTask = Task.Run(() => {  
                        while ((cbxSensors.Items.Count == 0)) {
                            Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
                        }     
                     } );
await Task.WhenAll(waitUntilFilledTask );

this.cbxSensors.SelectedItem = favorite.SensorName;
```

Comment: AFAIK, `Task` cannot be reused.

Comment: This is not a good idea.  WinForms/WPF operate an event loop.  You should subscribe to the combo box change events and update the selected item based on that.  You shouldn't sit there and poll for changes.

Comment: @CharlesMager But these change events are already suscribed to other functionalities. In fact I am using them implicitly in my code, every time I do `this.[myComboBox].SelectedItem`. Inside the handler function, I could use a global variable to indicate which case should be chosen... but the clarity of the code would decrease drastically if I did that.